# How to Find Areas Between Polar Curves Without Resorting to Graphing

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Note: Assume that any solutions are limited to $$0\leq\theta\leq2\pi.$$
How do you consistently find polar areas without graphing the given curve(s)? I.e, suppose we wish to find the area between the loops of $$r=4+8\cos(\theta).$$
Setting the expression equal to zero in order to find points of intersection, we get
$$
4+8\cos(\theta)=0
8\cos(\theta)=-4
\cos(\theta)=\frac{-1}{2}
\theta=\frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{4\pi}{3}
.$$
I am confused about how to algebraically find the necessary integral(s) to solve for the correct area, which is $133.404$.

Consider another problem. Suppose we wish to find the common interior of $r=4(1+\sin(\theta))$ and $r=4(1-\sin(\theta))$. Setting the expressions equal, we get that $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$. I am still at a dilemma though, it being figuring out a reliable method to setup integrals without graphing the equations.

I would appreciate an explanation. From my understanding, the problems can be only so varying--either it's inside one shape and outside another or inside of both shapes.

Comment: This is just like trying to find the area between the graphs $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$, except with some added complications because things are strange when $r$ can be negative (like tracing out the shape in half the expected time).  But in general, you need to figure out where one function is the "outside" function and where the other is, then use the formula for the area inside a polar curve.  If $f$ and $g$ are never negative and have period $2\pi$, then you are just integrating $\int_0^{2\pi} |f(r)^2-g(r)^2|/2 dr$.,

Comment: Could you provide an example? When you say "never negative," what exactly do you mean? What if we only have one curve, as is the case with the first example of $r=4+8\cos(\theta)$?

Comment: By never negative, I mean it is a function that never takes negative values.  The example of $r=4+8\cos(\theta)$ takes negative values, and that makes reasoning about the graph a lot more complicated.  One could try to come up with special procedures for thinking about things when $r$ can change signs, or one can simply draw the graph and let visual intuition take over.

Comment: Unfortunately visual intuition is not an option--we're dealing with a visually-impaired person here, hence the inquiry

Comment: Then whenever $r$ is negative, you need to recognize that you $(r,\theta)=(-r,\theta+\pi)$, check if this is giving you a new piece of your curve or tracing over another part of the curve exactly, and break into a lot of cases.  It is.....not nice.  I have not tried to distill it into an actual method, because it would be horrible in practice to use.